# Filling a Polygon in C with point in Polygon Algorithm

Tags: c, graphics

I´m working on implementing an algorithm to fill polygons. I´m using this tutorial as reference: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/

and this is my code:

```
//point in polygon algorithm for filling polyons

void fill_polygon(Array *vx,Array *vy){
    int  nodes, nodeX[1000], pixelX, pixelY, i, j, swap,top,bot,right,left,polyCorners ;
    polyCorners = vx->used;
    if(polyCorners<=2){
        return;
    }

    bot = maximum(vy);
    top = minimum(vy);
    right = maximum(vx);
    left = minimum(vx);
    /*printf("Top %d  - Bot %d - Left %d - Right %d \n",top,bot,left,right);
    wait(40);*/
    for (pixelY=top; pixelY<bot; pixelY++) {

        //  building list of nodes
        nodes=0; j=polyCorners-1;
        for (i=0; i<polyCorners; i++) {
            if (vy->array[i]< pixelY && vy->array[j]>=pixelY
                ||  vy->array[j]< pixelY && vy->array[i]>= pixelY) {

                nodeX[nodes++]=(int) (vx->array[i]+(pixelY-vy->array[i])/(vy->array[j]-vy->array[i])*(vx->array[j]-vx->array[i])); 

            }
            j=i; 
        }   
        //   bubble sort
        i=0;
        while (i<nodes-1) {
            if (nodeX[i]>nodeX[i+1]) {
              swap=nodeX[i]; nodeX[i]=nodeX[i+1]; nodeX[i+1]=swap; if (i) i--; 
            }

            else {
              i++; 
            }
        }
     // filling pixels between nodes
        for (i=0; i<nodes; i+=2) {
            if   (nodeX[i  ]>=right) break;

            if   (nodeX[i+1]> left ) {
                if (nodeX[i  ]< left ) nodeX[i  ]=left ;
                if (nodeX[i+1]> right) nodeX[i+1]=right;
                for (pixelX=nodeX[i]; pixelX<nodeX[i+1]; pixelX++){

                    plot_pixel(pixelX,pixelY,current_color);
                }  
            }
        }       

    }
}
```

the `vx` and `vy` variables are arrays with the x and y coordinates of each vertex of the polygon. I have inspected this code for a long time and I still don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

This is the result I get when I draw a simple 4 sided polygon:
Before:
Figure I was drawing (This is not the exact same figure as the image below but it´s a 4 sided polygon too)
[image]

After:

[image]

If it helps, somehow when I draw a square the algorithm fills it correctly:

[image]

Can you help me find the bugs in my code?

Comment: I have not spotted a bug, but plainly the algorithm fails to interpolate (or perhaps use) the boundary crossings correctly. All x-left and x-right positions are vertex coordinates. That's why the square works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I´m basing my code on the tutorial in the link above. Is that reference also managin the boundary crossings? Or is it just my code?

Comment: I don't know but its author thanked one contributor for pointing out a bug. Perhaps you should figure out how the algorithm works, rather than just copy it. You can put in debug prints easily, since it goes wrong on the very first raster.

Comment: Thanks. I´ve solved the issue, it was because I was using integers on my variables and that made problems with precision of the calculations. Changing them to double solved it :)

Comment: I was going to mention that but got distracted by your `int` types. The example you gave does not make the data types clear either.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> vx->array[i]+(pixelY-vy->array[i])/(vy->array[j]-vy->array[i])*(vx->array[j]-vx->array[i])
> ```

Assuming these are all integers, this will do integer division. That is, it will throw away the fractional part after the division.

You could cast one of the numbers involved to a `double` first, to do `double` division:

```
vx->array[i]+(pixelY-vy->array[i])/(double)(vy->array[j]-vy->array[i])*(vx->array[j]-vx->array[i])
                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

or you could swap the order of operations so the multiplication happens first. (However, this may cause overflow, if the numbers are big enough)

```
vx->array[i]+(pixelY-vy->array[i])*(vx->array[j]-vx->array[i])/(vy->array[j]-vy->array[i])
```